# TinyMCE not working properly with ng2-modal

Tags: angular, tinymce, bootstrap-modal, ng2-bootstrap

I'm using ng2-bootstrap for my Angular 4 application:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-modal

and I'm using TinyMCE editor inside the modal. Running TinyMCE editor inside bootstrap modal is a pain and I saw everyone complaining about it on online forums.
Doing some research I found out that the editor will work in bootstrap modal if it is initialized after the modal is open, so this is what I did:

```
initialize() {
 setTimeout(() => {
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#editor',
    plugins: ['link', 'table', 'lists'],
    skin_url: '/assets/skins/lightgray',
    toolbar: [
      'bold italic underline
    ],
    statusbar: false,
    link_context_toolbar: false,
    default_link_target: '_blank',
    link_assume_external_targets: true,
    setup: editor => {
      this.editor = editor;
      editor.on('keyup change', (e) => {
        const content = editor.getContent();
      });
    }
  });
}, 1000);
}
```

and I'm running this initialize after the modal is open (by calling a method on 'onOpen' event that ng2-bootstrap's modal provide). This approach works perfectly fine, but the only issue is the editor appears after 1 second, which is a really bad user experience. So how can I make sure that the initialization happens only after the modal is open (other than putting a timeout on it)?

Answer (score 0):

That particular Github project you are using only emits 3 events so you are limited to the events it emits.

From looking at the source code the events are:

```
@Output()
public onOpen = new EventEmitter(false);

@Output()
public onClose = new EventEmitter(false);

@Output()
public onSubmit = new EventEmitter(false);
```

One of them is `onOpen` - if the DOM elements are there when `onOpen` is triggered you could run your init at that point. They key is to not run the init call until the DOM elements are available on the page.

I would note that the Git repo for that project is archived so you likely won't get any help from the repo owner if the code needs enhancements.

Comment: thanks for the reply @Michael, but thats the first thing that I did, it didnt work. I'm not sure when does this onOpen event gets fired, I don't think its getting fired after the modal has been rendered on the DOM.